# Can you programatically tell if the webcam is in use?

Tags: macos, mac, webcam, imac, isight

I'm trying to run some commands when I start and stop using the (built in) webcam on my 2015 iMac running Catalina.

It sounds like historically `lsof | grep "AppleCamera"` would once tell me if the webcam is being used. However I'm not getting that to work on Catalina, is there an alternative process name or other method?

Comment: You may have a better luck finding a solution apple.stackexchange.com

Comment: Thanks. I've had a suggestion there. See: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/394887/can-you-programatically-tell-if-the-webcam-is-in-use

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has been cross-posted and received answers on Apple stackexchange.